# Select Statements within sql - functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

my problem goes as follows. I want to create a sql-function witch gets an integer as a parameter and returns a matching segment. The ranges for the different segemnts are in another table so I have to select the ranges in order to calculate which segment the given integer belongs to.

Apperently it is not possible to select data from a tabel within a sql-function. Do you have any ideas?

I'm working with the MS SQL Server 2008.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you not make this into a Stored Procedure???

Comment: "Apperently it is not possible to select data from a tabel within a sql-function." <-- this statement is incorrect.  Sample data and code would help people help you.

Comment: Have a look at this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms191320.aspx the very first example selects data from table and returns the selected value as a result. What is your problem?

Comment: Thank you everybody. Now it works. I had to change from 'Select ...' to 'Set ...'